# How can I look into a cell with VBA to find specific text, then extract it?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a column that can contain cells that have data that is split by a | delimiter. I need to be able to look into each cell and find specific text and if found extract all the text between the |'s.

For example: cell A2 has 
`blue story 1|red tree 2|orange flower 3|green car 4`

I want to be able to extract `red tree 2` by using the function `InStr` (If there is a better function please advice!)

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Sub test()

Dim Field As Variant, rng As Range, cell As Range
Set rng = Range("A1:A5")

For Each cell In rng.Cells
    If InStr(cell.Value, "Red") > 0 Then
    Field = Split(cell.Value, "|")
    Cells(cell.Row, 2).Value = Field
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

There is clearly a logical error because it outputs the first texts of the | in the array and not the actual one containing "Red".

Edit: I need it to be able to find "Red" in any given array and if out output that array in the column next to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not too far off: Split() returns a 0-based array of strings like this:

```
Split Array (0): blue story 1
Split Array (1): red tree 2
Split Array (2): orange flower 3
Split Array (3): green car 6
```

so to fix your code you need to check each value in the array:

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim fld As Variant, rng As Range, cell As Range, i As Long

    Set rng = Range("A1:A5")

    For Each cell In rng.Cells
        If InStr(1, cell.Value, "Red", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            fld = Split(cell.Value, "|")
            For i = 0 To UBound(fld)
                If InStr(1, fld(i), "Red", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                    Cells(cell.Row, 2).Value = fld(i)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

---

You could also use Text to Columns, or a formula like this

```
=MID(A2,SEARCH("Red",A2,1),SEARCH("|",A2,SEARCH("Red",A2,1))-SEARCH("Red",A2,1))
```

Comment: Thank you but what if red is not in array 1? I just gave an example but let's say red can be anywhere within the array.

Comment: Also thx you for the alternatives however when using this in a real setting for what I am trying to do, unlike the example, text to columns would make more of a headache since I will be using this on data that contains very very long text and 8+ delimiters.

Comment: If red is not found the code will not output anything. To get more alternatives you'll need to provide more context: what does the entire sheet look like **before** and what do you expect it to look like **after**. For example if you're forced to iterate through each cell you could copy each column into an array and perform the compare in memory (much fater), but then where do you want to place the results? (another sheet?). You could also use an AutoFilter: `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns(1).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*Red*"`, (many options depending on what you're trying to accomplish)

Comment: But within the context of your initial question (the example) - does the answer solve the problem?

Comment: Technically it does however I need it to be able to look through the list of arrays and find for example, "Red", and if found, output to the column next to it. Red is not always going to be in an array that is known like in the example you gave.

Comment: Nevermind my previous comments, I believe it works as is. Thank you!

Comment: I think you want to make the color dynamic - if that's the case I can provide more details and an example to show how it can be implemented

Comment: the code you provided works as is! No need to implement anything else.